# wxWidgets has some sort of garbage collector?

Tags: c++, c, memory, garbage-collection, wxwidgets

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, -1, _("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50),
                                  wxSize(450, 350));       
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

This code works fine and it is the kind of code if seen out there. I allocate a wxFrame on the heap and I never worry about the memory, does wxWidgets collects it's own garbage?

Comment: You might want to read http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Avoiding_Memory_Leaks for answers to this. Basic answer is no, it doesn't, and the code you posted has a memory leak.

Comment: Thou shalt not edit thy question into a completely different question.

Comment: @yuushi isnt the first toplevel window you create registered as the apps main window?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, you might be right. I'm going back and looking at my stuff around code with wxWidgets, and realized I've always created a separate class which inherits from wxFrame, then defined an onExit() method which destroys the frame. I'm not so sure of my initial comment now. Hopefully someone with more experience with wxWidgets can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is how you should handle windows with wxWidgets. The reference says that you particularly **must not** delete them, and that you can request them to be destroyed with `wxWindow::Destroy`. The default behavior of a frame closed by user action is that the frame is destroyed.

There is no garbage collection as such (e.g a `new wxString()` will leak unless deleted), but the memory for some classes will be automatically managed by the library.

[wxWidgets window deletion overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_windowdeletionoverview.html#windowdeletionoverview)

Comment: The [application shutdown behavior](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxappoverview.html#wxappshutdownoverview) should also be noted here.